# Insert Data into Dynamic Table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

SP to insert data into IntermediateSMSTable,

IntermediateSMSTable will be input param as db details is of client db hence can be configurable from application level.

Below are the details:

```
Input params:  @SMSData,  IntermediateSMSTable

XML format of @SMSData as below:

<SMS>
<DETAILS NID="123" MNO="98745124" MSG="AAAA" SID="123" DATE="12-03-2014" />
</SMS>

IntermediateSMSTable = Server.DataBase.Table   


INSERT INTO IntermediateSMSTable (CODE, PHONE, TEXT, MISC_DATA, DATE) VALUES (strSmsNotificationID, strMobileNo,strMessage,ScheduleID,getdate())
```

Comment: That is going to require quite a bit of dynamic sql where you'll need to match the table-structure to the data in the xml (I', assuming not all tables look the same).
Wouldn't it be easier to do this directly in the calling application?

Comment: Why do you need to do it in an SP? Let the application level generate the insert statement directly.